Screenshot in Android with MediaProjection
I am a newbie in android programmin and write small application with Kotlin in Android Studio 2024. I need make screenshot of another application. I see MediaProjection as good way. My app has MainActivity and service.  When executing
projection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data!!)
i error
"Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION"
and app crashes. I see many docs, add notifications, permissions, but no luck. Need help!
package com.example.screenshot

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat
import java.util.*
import com.example.screenshot.Capture

class MainActivity : Activity() {

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CAPTURE = 1

        var projection: MediaProjection? = null
    }
    private lateinit var mediaProjectionManager: MediaProjectionManager
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val startServiceButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.start_service_button)
        val stopServiceButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.stop_service_button)

        mediaProjectionManager = getSystemService(Service.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
        startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent() , REQUEST_CAPTURE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, CaptureService::class.java)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                .setAction(CaptureService.ACTION_ENABLE_CAPTURE)
                startForegroundService(intent)
                Thread.sleep(100)
            projection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data!!)
                Toast.makeText(this, "All OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()                
            } else {
                projection = null
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
            //finish()
    }
}

package com.example.screenshot

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat
import java.util.*
import com.example.screenshot.Capture

class CaptureService : Service() {

    companion object {
        private val TAG = CaptureService::class.qualifiedName
        val ACTION_ENABLE_CAPTURE = "enable_capture"
    }

    private val notificationId = Random().nextInt()

    private val capture = Capture(this)
    
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent != null) {

            when (intent.action) {
                ACTION_ENABLE_CAPTURE -> onEnableCapture()
            }
        }

            val channelId = "001"
            val channelName = "myChannel"
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
            channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            val manager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            val notification: Notification =
                Notification.Builder(applicationContext, channelId).setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setCategory(
                        Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE
                    ).build()
        ServiceCompat.startForeground(this,1,notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION)
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun enableCapture() {
        if (MainActivity.projection == null) {
            println("Phase1")
            Log.d(TAG, "startActivity(CaptureActivity)")
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            onEnableCapture()
        }
    }

    private fun onEnableCapture() {
       MainActivity.projection?.run {
            capture.run(this) {
                capture.stop()
                // save bitmap
            }
        }
    }

    private fun disableCapture() {
        capture.stop()        
        MainActivity.projection = null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        disableCapture()        
    }
}

package com.example.screenshot

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay
import android.media.ImageReader
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

class Capture(val context: Context) : ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {

    companion object {
        val TAG = Capture::class.qualifiedName
    }

    private var display: VirtualDisplay? = null
    private var onCaptureListener: ((Bitmap) -> Unit)? = null

    fun run(mediaProjection: MediaProjection, onCaptureListener: (Bitmap) -> Unit) {
        this.onCaptureListener = onCaptureListener
        if (display == null) {
            display = createDisplay(mediaProjection)
        }
    }

    private fun createDisplay(mediaProjection: MediaProjection): VirtualDisplay {
        context.resources.displayMetrics.run {
            val maxImages = 2
            val reader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                widthPixels, heightPixels, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, maxImages)
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this@Capture, null)
            val display = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "Capture Display", widthPixels, heightPixels, densityDpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                reader.surface, null, null)
            Log.d(TAG, "createVirtualDisplay")
            return display
        }
    }

    override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        if (display != null) {
            onCaptureListener?.invoke(captureImage(reader))
        }
    }

    private fun captureImage(reader: ImageReader): Bitmap {
        val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
        context.resources.displayMetrics.run {
            image.planes[0].run {
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    rowStride / pixelStride, heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
                image.close()                
                return bitmap
            }
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        display?.release()
        display = null
        onCaptureListener = null
    }
}

My AndroidManifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScreenShot"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ScreenShot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".CaptureService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />
            />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
</manifest>

Added permission to AndroidManifest - same problem
Added notifications to service - same problem

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792576/take-a-screenshot-from-a-service-using-mediaprojection Notice, how to properly pass the data to the service and create the projection in the service, not in the activity.

I have add notification code to service from this article - no luck.

Manifest service declaration is same, I think

The point is that the service has not completely started yet when you're calling getMediaProjection. You must call getMediaProjection at the end of onStartCommand.

Thanks, i will try move mediaProjection init to service

Thanks for help. I moved getMediaProjection to service but now my projection is null.
